# The difference between 送 ,带 and 捎

Tags: verbs

I know that they all mean something like "to bring something to someone" and 送
also means "to see someone out" and "to give sm a present"
but what is the difference between these three verbs in these sentences?
1)他给我带来一些东西.
2)他给我捎来一些东西.
3)他给我送来一些东西.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

【送】

一、Send something to somebody, this means You **intentionally** bring something to someone with your own payment, and this thing orignally belongs to you. This is usually used when you wanna go to pay a visit, or you wanna invite someone, to be in honor of something……ect.

E.g：

1. 明天小明过生日了，我们**送**什么好呢？（Tomorrow is XiaoMing's birthday, what can we buy to send him as a present?）
2. 今天是我们结婚的纪念日，我**送**你一枚戒指（I'd like to send you a ring for the anniversary of our wedding today.）

二、Can be also used you want to give someone something intentionally (for some special purpose, either good or bad).

E.g：

1. 我**送**她一束花，我爱她。(I sent her a bunch of flowers because of my love to
   her).
2. 我**送**领导1000元红包，希望仕途顺利( I sent my boss 1000 RMB for my future
   official career).

三、 The way of "sending someone something" by using “送” **NOT ONLY MEANS**"Person To Person". But Just enpharsis "Something to the destination". So you can say：

我寄了它一个包裹，**送**他一个表. (I sent him a package with a watch inside).

【带】

Bring something to somebody. The way to "give someone something" MUST BE "Person To Person". And this usually has two meanings (either will be OK):

1. The object to be brought to others isn't yours.
2. Maybe you have a purpose to bring this thing to others, and this isn't your main aim. You just do it "buy the way" (=捎)

E.g:

1. 今天小王生病了，请给他**带**作业本。(Please bring the workbook to XiaoWang, because he's ill today).
2. 我去了一次南京，顺便给他**带**点好吃的东西. (I had a trip to Nanjig, and by the way, I brought him something good to eat).

【捎】

This word CAN BE ONLY USED wihtout any purposes, this means when you do something, you see that this could be also good/favourate to others. So you also do that "by the way"：

你既然要去看阿姨，我就不去了。顺便请**捎**给她我的问候，谢谢。

(Since you are going to your aunt's, Please bring my greetings to her as well and I won't go there. Thanks).

For “捎”，you can also say “捎带” instead.

Answer (score 0):

1)他给我带来一些东西.

- He brought me something. (commonly used in literature)

2)他给我捎来一些东西.

- He brought me something. (with a subtle emphasis that "something" was on his way, he did not bring those explicitly)

3)他给我送来一些东西.

- He brought/bought me something. (with a subtle emphasis that "something" is given to you for free)

Answer (score 0):

他给我带来一些东西，一般指小东西，不重要的东西。
他给我捎来一些东西，有顺便带来的意思，他也不一定亲自来。东西不太重要。
他给我送来一些东西，他要亲自过来！说明东西很重要！